# Hice un Trivial Con Preguntas Aleatorias Pero Quiero Que Las Preguntas No Se Repitan Pero No Se Como Hacerlo

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
        var preguntas = [
        "-Como Se Guarda un Archivo PHP?",
        "-Como Se Hace Una Funcion Random?",
        "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Codigo En El Aula?",
        "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Servidor Local?",
        "-Se Puede Usar Un If En Html?",
        "-Como Se Define Una Funcion?",
        "-Que Es Un Array?",
        "-Como Se Manda A Imprimir En Javascript?",
        "-Un Servidor Local Necesita Internet?",
        "-Que Es El PHP?",
        "-Menciona Los 3 Errores Basicos De Un Codigo De Html: ",
        "-Cuantos Objetos Se Pueden Poner En Un Archivo?",
        "-Que Es Un If?",
        "-Como Se Hace Un Comentario?",
        "-Que Es Un Echo?",
        "-Se Puede Poner Una Imagen En Html?","-Que Es El Rand?"

        ];
        var respuestas = [
        [".PHP", ".PNG", ".HTML", ".JS"],
        ["Rand", "Echo", "Var", "Id"],
        ["Blog De Notas", "Xampp", "Chrome", "Paint"],
        ["Xampp", "BlogNotas", "Chrome", "Youtube"],
        ["Abriendo Un Script", "Si", "No", "Tal Vez"],
        ["Ejemplo()", "var ejemplo", "mathrand", "src"],
        ["Es Una Variable Con Distintos Tipos De Valores En Una Sola Variable", "Sirve Para Agrandar Las Letras", "Pone Imagenes", "Es Un Temporizador"],
        ["document.write(ejemplo);", "printf(ejemplo)", "con una etiqueta p", "write(ejemplo)"],
        ["No Ya Que Por Eso Seria Un Servidor Local", "Si Necesita Es Obvio", "Algunas Ocasiones", "no lo se"],
        ["Es Un Lenguaje De Programacion Mas Sencillo Y Con Mas Funciones Pero Requiere Un Servidor Local", "Es Un Antivirus Practico", "Una Carpeta De Windows", "Un Navegador"],
        ["Errores Fatales, Advertencias Y Avisos", "Error", "Funciones Y Errores", "Advertencias"],
        ["Son Ilimitadas Siempre Y Cuando Se Sepa Como Manejarlas", "Menos De 10", "Ninguna", "Mas De 100"],
        ["Es Una Condicion Que Si Se Llega A Cumplir Se Hace Lo Que El Usuario Programo","Una Variable","Una Funcion","Un Servidor Local"],
        ["Ejemplo","\\Ejemplo","Solo Es Escribir","Ninguna De Las Anteriores"],
        ["Es Un Comando Que Se Usa Para Imprimir En Pantalla En PHP","Es Un Hecho","Es Un Boton","Es Una App"],
        ["Si Se Puede","Necesitas Una Extensión","No","Requiere Internet"],
        ["Sirve Para Arrojar Un Numero Aleatorio Sea Entero O Decimal O Un Texto","Es Una Funcion","Es Una App","Es Una Pagina Web"]

        ];
Aleatorio();

function Aleatorio(){

        var indice_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*preguntas.length);

        var respuestas_posibles = respuestas[indice_aleatorio];

        var posiciones = [0,1,2,3];
        var respuestas_reordenadas = [];

        var ya_se_metio = false;
        for(i in respuestas_posibles){
            var posicion_aleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random()*posiciones.length);
            if(posicion_aleatoria==0 && ya_se_metio == false){
                indicie_respuesta_correcta =i;
                ya_se_metio = true;
            }
            respuestas_reordenadas[i] = respuestas_posibles[posiciones[posicion_aleatoria]];
            posiciones.splice(posicion_aleatoria, 1);
        }

        var txt_respuestas="";
        for(i in respuestas_reordenadas){
            txt_respuestas += '<input type="radio" name="pp" value="'+i+'"><label>'+respuestas_reordenadas[i]+'</label><br>';
        }

        document.getElementById("respuestas").innerHTML = txt_respuestas;
        document.getElementById("pregunta").innerHTML = preguntas[indice_aleatorio];

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apartir de ese arreglo que siempre va a estar ordenado de acuerdo a como tu lo digitaste, puedes hacer un scramble del array o los arrays que necesites, es decir, hacer una copia de cada arreglo que quieras que sus datos no se repitan (ya que veo que tus datos no se repiten en ninguno de los arrays), y luego usar un generador que te arroje los datos de uno en uno hasta el final (los datos del array scrambleado), no se como se diga en español.

Partamos de lo basico, primero decir que para que todo sea mas fácil deberías almacenar las preguntas y las respuestas en un mismo array que las contenga, es decir, en vez de tener esto:

```
var preguntas = [
        "-Como Se Guarda un Archivo PHP?",
        "-Como Se Hace Una Funcion Random?",
        "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Codigo En El Aula?",
        "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Servidor Local?",
        "-Se Puede Usar Un If En Html?",
        "-Como Se Define Una Funcion?",
        "-Que Es Un Array?",
        "-Como Se Manda A Imprimir En Javascript?",
        "-Un Servidor Local Necesita Internet?",
        "-Que Es El PHP?",
        "-Menciona Los 3 Errores Basicos De Un Codigo De Html: ",
        "-Cuantos Objetos Se Pueden Poner En Un Archivo?",
        "-Que Es Un If?",
        "-Como Se Hace Un Comentario?",
        "-Que Es Un Echo?",
        "-Se Puede Poner Una Imagen En Html?","-Que Es El Rand?"

];

var respuestas = [
            [".PHP", ".PNG", ".HTML", ".JS"],
            ["Rand", "Echo", "Var", "Id"],
            ["Blog De Notas", "Xampp", "Chrome", "Paint"],
            ["Xampp", "BlogNotas", "Chrome", "Youtube"],
            ["Abriendo Un Script", "Si", "No", "Tal Vez"],
            ["Ejemplo()", "var ejemplo", "mathrand", "src"],
            ["Es Una Variable Con Distintos Tipos De Valores En Una Sola Variable", "Sirve Para Agrandar Las Letras", "Pone Imagenes", "Es Un Temporizador"],
            ["document.write(ejemplo);", "printf(ejemplo)", "con una etiqueta p", "write(ejemplo)"],
            ["No Ya Que Por Eso Seria Un Servidor Local", "Si Necesita Es Obvio", "Algunas Ocasiones", "no lo se"],
            ["Es Un Lenguaje De Programacion Mas Sencillo Y Con Mas Funciones Pero Requiere Un Servidor Local", "Es Un Antivirus Practico", "Una Carpeta De Windows", "Un Navegador"],
            ["Errores Fatales, Advertencias Y Avisos", "Error", "Funciones Y Errores", "Advertencias"],
            ["Son Ilimitadas Siempre Y Cuando Se Sepa Como Manejarlas", "Menos De 10", "Ninguna", "Mas De 100"],
            ["Es Una Condicion Que Si Se Llega A Cumplir Se Hace Lo Que El Usuario Programo","Una Variable","Una Funcion","Un Servidor Local"],
            ["Ejemplo","\\Ejemplo","Solo Es Escribir","Ninguna De Las Anteriores"],
            ["Es Un Comando Que Se Usa Para Imprimir En Pantalla En PHP","Es Un Hecho","Es Un Boton","Es Una App"],
            ["Si Se Puede","Necesitas Una Extensión","No","Requiere Internet"],
            ["Sirve Para Arrojar Un Numero Aleatorio Sea Entero O Decimal O Un Texto","Es Una Funcion","Es Una App","Es Una Pagina Web"]

];
```

Tener esto:

```
const preguntas = [
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Guarda un Archivo PHP?",
        respuestas: [".PHP", ".PNG", ".HTML", ".JS"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Hace Una Funcion Random?",
        respuestas: ["Rand", "Echo", "Var", "Id"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Codigo En El Aula?",
        respuestas: ["Blog De Notas", "Xampp", "Chrome", "Paint"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Servidor Local?",
        respuestas: ["Xampp", "BlogNotas", "Chrome", "Youtube"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Se Puede Usar Un If En Html?",
        respuestas: ["Abriendo Un Script", "Si", "No", "Tal Vez"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Define Una Funcion?",
        respuestas: ["Ejemplo()", "var ejemplo", "mathrand", "src"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un Array?",
        respuestas: ["Es Una Variable Con Distintos Tipos De Valores En Una Sola Variable", "Sirve Para Agrandar Las Letras", "Pone Imagenes", "Es Un Temporizador"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Manda A Imprimir En Javascript?",
        respuestas: ["document.write(ejemplo);", "printf(ejemplo)", "con una etiqueta p", "write(ejemplo)"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Un Servidor Local Necesita Internet?",
        respuestas: ["No Ya Que Por Eso Seria Un Servidor Local", "Si Necesita Es Obvio", "Algunas Ocasiones", "no lo se"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es El PHP?",
        respuestas: ["Es Un Lenguaje De Programacion Mas Sencillo Y Con Mas Funciones Pero Requiere Un Servidor Local", "Es Un Antivirus Practico", "Una Carpeta De Windows", "Un Navegador"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Menciona Los 3 Errores Basicos De Un Codigo De Html: ",
        respuestas: ["Errores Fatales, Advertencias Y Avisos", "Error", "Funciones Y Errores", "Advertencias"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Cuantos Objetos Se Pueden Poner En Un Archivo?",
        respuestas: ["Son Ilimitadas Siempre Y Cuando Se Sepa Como Manejarlas", "Menos De 10", "Ninguna", "Mas De 100"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un If?",
        respuestas: ["Es Una Condicion Que Si Se Llega A Cumplir Se Hace Lo Que El Usuario Programo","Una Variable","Una Funcion","Un Servidor Local"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Hace Un Comentario?",
        respuestas: ["Ejemplo","\\Ejemplo","Solo Es Escribir","Ninguna De Las Anteriores"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un Echo?",
        respuestas: ["Es Un Comando Que Se Usa Para Imprimir En Pantalla En PHP","Es Un Hecho","Es Un Boton","Es Una App"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Se Puede Poner Una Imagen En Html?",
        respuestas: ["Si Se Puede","Necesitas Una Extensión","No","Requiere Internet"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es El Rand?",
        respuestas: ["Sirve Para Arrojar Un Numero Aleatorio Sea Entero O Decimal O Un Texto","Es Una Funcion","Es Una App","Es Una Pagina Web"]
    }

];
```

Sí, se que se ve mas largo, pero te da mejor control a la hora de saber que pregunta tiene cuales respuestas y etc, ademas como se agrupan las preguntas y respuestas el revolverlos será mas sencillo, ahora es cuestion de crear un arreglo revuelto de preguntas y respuestas:

```js
const preguntas = [
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Guarda un Archivo PHP?",
        respuestas: [".PHP", ".PNG", ".HTML", ".JS"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Hace Una Funcion Random?",
        respuestas: ["Rand", "Echo", "Var", "Id"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Codigo En El Aula?",
        respuestas: ["Blog De Notas", "Xampp", "Chrome", "Paint"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Servidor Local?",
        respuestas: ["Xampp", "BlogNotas", "Chrome", "Youtube"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Se Puede Usar Un If En Html?",
        respuestas: ["Abriendo Un Script", "Si", "No", "Tal Vez"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Define Una Funcion?",
        respuestas: ["Ejemplo()", "var ejemplo", "mathrand", "src"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un Array?",
        respuestas: ["Es Una Variable Con Distintos Tipos De Valores En Una Sola Variable", "Sirve Para Agrandar Las Letras", "Pone Imagenes", "Es Un Temporizador"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Manda A Imprimir En Javascript?",
        respuestas: ["document.write(ejemplo);", "printf(ejemplo)", "con una etiqueta p", "write(ejemplo)"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Un Servidor Local Necesita Internet?",
        respuestas: ["No Ya Que Por Eso Seria Un Servidor Local", "Si Necesita Es Obvio", "Algunas Ocasiones", "no lo se"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es El PHP?",
        respuestas: ["Es Un Lenguaje De Programacion Mas Sencillo Y Con Mas Funciones Pero Requiere Un Servidor Local", "Es Un Antivirus Practico", "Una Carpeta De Windows", "Un Navegador"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Menciona Los 3 Errores Basicos De Un Codigo De Html: ",
        respuestas: ["Errores Fatales, Advertencias Y Avisos", "Error", "Funciones Y Errores", "Advertencias"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Cuantos Objetos Se Pueden Poner En Un Archivo?",
        respuestas: ["Son Ilimitadas Siempre Y Cuando Se Sepa Como Manejarlas", "Menos De 10", "Ninguna", "Mas De 100"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un If?",
        respuestas: ["Es Una Condicion Que Si Se Llega A Cumplir Se Hace Lo Que El Usuario Programo","Una Variable","Una Funcion","Un Servidor Local"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Hace Un Comentario?",
        respuestas: ["Ejemplo","\\Ejemplo","Solo Es Escribir","Ninguna De Las Anteriores"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un Echo?",
        respuestas: ["Es Un Comando Que Se Usa Para Imprimir En Pantalla En PHP","Es Un Hecho","Es Un Boton","Es Una App"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Se Puede Poner Una Imagen En Html?",
        respuestas: ["Si Se Puede","Necesitas Una Extensión","No","Requiere Internet"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es El Rand?",
        respuestas: ["Sirve Para Arrojar Un Numero Aleatorio Sea Entero O Decimal O Un Texto","Es Una Funcion","Es Una App","Es Una Pagina Web"]
    }

];

function scrambleArray(array){

   const scrambledArr = [];
   
   for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

      let index = (Math.random() * array.length) | 0;
      if(scrambledArr.length != 0){

        let j = 0;
        while(j < scrambledArr.length){

          if(scrambledArr[j].pregunta == array[index].pregunta){
            j = 0;
            index = (Math.random() * array.length) | 0;
          }else{
            j++;
          }

        }

        scrambledArr.push(array[index]);
      }else{
        scrambledArr.push(array[index]);
      }

   }
   
   return scrambledArr;

}

//Array scrambleado en base a tus preguntas, nunca se repiten.
let preguntasAleatoriasSinRepetir = scrambleArray(preguntas);
console.log(preguntasAleatoriasSinRepetir);
```

Ahora es solo cuestión de usar algo muy útil para tu caso, llamado `generador` un generador no es mas que una función que mantiene su estado y devuelve valores diferentes en cada caso:

```
function* dameLaSiguientePregunta(arrayPreguntas){

   while(true){
       yield* arrayPreguntas;
   }

}
```

Notese como aparentemente hay un bucle infinito en el generador, pero no, esto no es necesariamente así, el bucle no es infinito, lo que es infinito es lo que devolvera el array, no en el sentido que se ejecute una absurda cantidad de vecez el bucle, ya que solo se ejecuta una vez por cada llamado al metodo next del generador, lo que pasa es que esta es una manera de crear un `generador` que nunca termine y que siempre devuelva valores y encima manteniendo su estado, es decir una vez se terminen los datos que el generador debe regresar, comienza desde 0 de nuevo, esto es muy útil si lo que quieres es que el generador siempre tenga preguntas para darte, aunque la lista haya acabado.

En caso de que no quieras este comportamiento entonces puedes usar esta otra versión del generador:

```
function* dameLaSiguientePregunta(arrayPreguntas){
   yield* arrayPreguntas;
}
```

Donde la palabra reservada `yield`, que hace parte del generador es como un return dinamico, que nos devuelve diferentes valores dependiendo de lo que necesitemos, sin embargo ten en cuenta que el generador de arriba, una vez termine de iterar por todos los elementos, (una vez llames al generador la cantidad de vecez que tengas de elementos en tu array), este se dará por terminado y jamas nunca te dara un valor del array, si lo ejecutas estando el generador terminado no te dara errores, simplemente te devolvera undefined, es decir, cuando no hayan mas preguntas, dejara de tener preguntas para darte.

Sin mas entonces el código ejemplo completo sería este:

```js
const preguntas = [
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Guarda un Archivo PHP?",
        respuestas: [".PHP", ".PNG", ".HTML", ".JS"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Hace Una Funcion Random?",
        respuestas: ["Rand", "Echo", "Var", "Id"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Codigo En El Aula?",
        respuestas: ["Blog De Notas", "Xampp", "Chrome", "Paint"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Con Que Programa Se Hizo El Servidor Local?",
        respuestas: ["Xampp", "BlogNotas", "Chrome", "Youtube"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Se Puede Usar Un If En Html?",
        respuestas: ["Abriendo Un Script", "Si", "No", "Tal Vez"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Define Una Funcion?",
        respuestas: ["Ejemplo()", "var ejemplo", "mathrand", "src"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un Array?",
        respuestas: ["Es Una Variable Con Distintos Tipos De Valores En Una Sola Variable", "Sirve Para Agrandar Las Letras", "Pone Imagenes", "Es Un Temporizador"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Manda A Imprimir En Javascript?",
        respuestas: ["document.write(ejemplo);", "printf(ejemplo)", "con una etiqueta p", "write(ejemplo)"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Un Servidor Local Necesita Internet?",
        respuestas: ["No Ya Que Por Eso Seria Un Servidor Local", "Si Necesita Es Obvio", "Algunas Ocasiones", "no lo se"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es El PHP?",
        respuestas: ["Es Un Lenguaje De Programacion Mas Sencillo Y Con Mas Funciones Pero Requiere Un Servidor Local", "Es Un Antivirus Practico", "Una Carpeta De Windows", "Un Navegador"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Menciona Los 3 Errores Basicos De Un Codigo De Html: ",
        respuestas: ["Errores Fatales, Advertencias Y Avisos", "Error", "Funciones Y Errores", "Advertencias"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Cuantos Objetos Se Pueden Poner En Un Archivo?",
        respuestas: ["Son Ilimitadas Siempre Y Cuando Se Sepa Como Manejarlas", "Menos De 10", "Ninguna", "Mas De 100"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un If?",
        respuestas: ["Es Una Condicion Que Si Se Llega A Cumplir Se Hace Lo Que El Usuario Programo","Una Variable","Una Funcion","Un Servidor Local"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Como Se Hace Un Comentario?",
        respuestas: ["Ejemplo","\\Ejemplo","Solo Es Escribir","Ninguna De Las Anteriores"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es Un Echo?",
        respuestas: ["Es Un Comando Que Se Usa Para Imprimir En Pantalla En PHP","Es Un Hecho","Es Un Boton","Es Una App"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Se Puede Poner Una Imagen En Html?",
        respuestas: ["Si Se Puede","Necesitas Una Extensión","No","Requiere Internet"]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "-Que Es El Rand?",
        respuestas: ["Sirve Para Arrojar Un Numero Aleatorio Sea Entero O Decimal O Un Texto","Es Una Funcion","Es Una App","Es Una Pagina Web"]
    }

];

function scrambleArray(array){

   const scrambledArr = [];
   
   for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

      let index = (Math.random() * array.length) | 0;
      if(scrambledArr.length != 0){

        let j = 0;
        while(j < scrambledArr.length){

          if(scrambledArr[j].pregunta == array[index].pregunta){
            j = 0;
            index = (Math.random() * array.length) | 0;
          }else{
            j++;
          }

        }

        scrambledArr.push(array[index]);
      }else{
        scrambledArr.push(array[index]);
      }

   }
   
   return scrambledArr;

}

function* dameLaSiguientePregunta(arrayPreguntas){

    while(true){
        yield* arrayPreguntas;
    }
 
}
 
let preguntasAleatoriasSinRepetir = scrambleArray(preguntas);
let generadorDePreguntas = dameLaSiguientePregunta(preguntasAleatoriasSinRepetir);

console.log("\nPregunta 1: \n");
console.log(generadorDePreguntas.next().value);
console.log("\nPregunta 2: \n");
console.log(generadorDePreguntas.next().value);
console.log("\nPregunta 3: \n");
console.log(generadorDePreguntas.next().value);
```

De esta manera puedes obtener un objeto que contiene una pregunta y sus respectivas respuestas cada vez que llames a `generadorDePreguntas.next().value` y la pregunta siempre será diferente.

Ademas recuerda que el generador va con respecto a un array desordenado osea scrambleamos el array por lo cuál no hay posibilidad que se repitan las preguntas y ademas el orden de las preguntas siempre es diferente.

Comment: Y bueno, cabe mencionar que en los objetos, para acceder a la propiedad pregunta por ejemplo sería nombreObjeto.clave, es decir objeto.pregunta y objeto.respuestas, donde objeto.respuestas te dará el arreglo de respuestas de esa pregunta, es decir que puedes accederlas por separado si quieres aunque esten encapsuladas juntas.